# Masquerade over USB Ethernet Problem

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, iptables

I am trying to create a hotspot with a captive portal for my company. First thing I needed to do was share my internet access.

So, what I am trying to do is, have internet cable plugged into eth0, then make it accessible from eth1

**eth0 is regular NIC, but eth1 is USB Ethernet**

#### I did the following:

1. edited "/etc/network/interfaces":

> auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> auto eth1
>   iface eth1 inet static
>   address 192.168.3.1
>   network 192.168.3.0
>   netmask 255.255.255.0

2. restarted the networking service
3. edited "/etc/sysctl.conf" and uncommented the following line:

> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

4. I entered the following line to masquerade:

> sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

=======================================================

- When I type **ifconfig**

> **eth0**      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>             inet addr:192.168.1.109  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::de4a:3eff:fef2:db6e/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:2247 (2.2 KB)  TX bytes:7133 (7.1 KB)
>
> **eth1**      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>             inet addr:192.168.3.1  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe53:4458/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:15 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:901 (901.0 B)  TX bytes:9214 (9.2 KB)
>
> **lo**        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
>             RX bytes:86369 (86.3 KB)  TX bytes:86369 (86.3 KB)

- when i type **sudo iptables -t nat -L -v -n**

> Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 118 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination      
>       2   118 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

#### Additional Info

- My NICs had different names when I first installed Ubuntu, they were something like enp2s0 for eth0 and some long name for eth1, I changed their names.
- One last thing I should mention, although I am not sure it is relevant, when I try to access my networks from "system settings" GUI, I get this error message "Did not find a connection with UUID '(null)'"

My problem is that I still can't access the internet from eth1, which is connected to linksys wireless router internet source plug. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated..